# How to do a left outer join on inequality?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following SQL query on BigQuery. I am trying to join two different tables one of which is a much smaller table than the other. At first I used the regular join but this results in elimination of some of the data that I am working with.

```
with weekly_periods as(
select
    ticket_id,
    start_time_in_minutes_from_week,
    raw_delta_in_minutes,
    week_number,
    greatest(0, start_time_in_minutes_from_week - week_number * (7 * 24 * 60)) as ticket_week_start_time,
    least(start_time_in_minutes_from_week + raw_delta_in_minutes - week_number * (7 * 24 * 60),(7 * 24 * 60)) as ticket_week_end_time
from
    ticket_solved_time,
    unnest(generate_array(0, floor((start_time_in_minutes_from_week + raw_delta_in_minutes) / (7 * 24 * 60)), 1)) as week_number,
    intercepted_periods as(
        select
            ticket_id,
            week_number,
            ticket_week_start_time,
            ticket_week_end_time,
            schedule.start_time as schedule_start_time,
            schedule.end_time as schedule_end_time,
            least(ticket_week_end_time, schedule.end_time) - greatest(ticket_week_start_time, schedule.start_time) as scheduled_minutes
        from
            weekly_periods
            left join
                schedule
            on  ticket_week_start_time <= schedule.end_time
            and ticket_week_end_time >= schedule.start_time
```

But I am receiving an error of: -- LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join --

How would it be possible to do this join while preserving the data? If I just do JOIN the query doesn't not return the full result. 
Thank you!

Comment: query presented in  your question is a little junky and even if you will use equality join - will NOT work. please make sure to present correct version - so we will be able to help you without wasting our time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is use a cross join and then add your join condition in where clause as shown below:

```
with weekly_periods as(
select
    ticket_id,
    start_time_in_minutes_from_week,
    raw_delta_in_minutes,
    week_number,
    greatest(0, start_time_in_minutes_from_week - week_number * (7 * 24 * 60)) as ticket_week_start_time,
    least(start_time_in_minutes_from_week + raw_delta_in_minutes - week_number * (7 * 24 * 60),(7 * 24 * 60)) as ticket_week_end_time
from
    ticket_solved_time,
    unnest(generate_array(0, floor((start_time_in_minutes_from_week + raw_delta_in_minutes) / (7 * 24 * 60)), 1)) as week_number,
    intercepted_periods as(
        select
            ticket_id,
            week_number,
            ticket_week_start_time,
            ticket_week_end_time,
            schedule.start_time as schedule_start_time,
            schedule.end_time as schedule_end_time,
            least(ticket_week_end_time, schedule.end_time) - greatest(ticket_week_start_time, schedule.start_time) as scheduled_minutes
        from
            weekly_periods
            Cross join
                schedule
            Where  ticket_week_start_time <= schedule.end_time
            and ticket_week_end_time >= schedule.start_time
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables based on a relational key using an `=` operator (example below) then use `where` to implement your criteria...  Since you didn't post your table structure, this is just an example of the correct way to join

```
    left join
    schedule
    on  schedule.id = weekly_period.ticketid and 
        weekly_period.ticketid = intercepted_period.ticketid
    where
        ticket_week_start_time <= schedule.end_time
    and ticket_week_end_time >= schedule.start_time
```

Comment: Why was it then possible for the tables to be partially joined based on the inequality?